# Using UIEventSubtypeMotionShake event methods, Can I automatically launch my application without user interaction in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want open my application without user interaction, just shaking the device using `UIEventSubtypeMotionShake` event method and using location `postNotificationName` method in `AppDelegate`. is it possible to do...?

Comment: How would you set that up without your app running?  Also, your app doesn't receive events if it's not active.

Comment: Only the user can bring an app to the foreground, either by tapping the icon or a notification.

Comment: No, this is not possible. The only ways to launch the app are through user interaction... Opening a notification, clicking a link (that is authorised to open your app), tapping the icon, etc...